# What does 'otherwise' mean in the passage?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does ***otherwise*** mean in the passage? Does it mean ***in a different way***, or ***in a different situation***?

> In one experiment, a target individual who refused to complete a
> racist task was appreciated by neutral judges, but disliked by
> participants who had been asked to complete the racist task prior to
> the target — and who overwhelmingly did so without complaining. *To
> participants who had willingly gone along with the problematic
> behavior, the ***otherwise*** exemplary stance of the rebel apparently
> represented a threat to their moral self-regard*, which they addressed
> by putting him or her down, and reporting less respect for, and
> attraction to, the rebel. Demonstrating the role of the self-concept,
> participants whose self-concept had been secured before seeing the
> rebel (by reflecting on an important quality or value, and how they
> had recently demonstrated it) did not show the same backlash, even if
> they had done the racist task first. In fact, participants thus
> “self-affirmed” were able to learn from the rebel’s gesture. They
> admitted having had more freedom at the time of the task, and reported
> less comfort with their own choice.

[Personality, Identity, and Character: Explorations in Moral Psychology](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=a2p_Tg8c0N8C&pg=PA350&lpg=PA350&dq=the%20otherwise%20exemplary%20stance%20of%20the%20rebel%20apparently%20represented%20a%20threat%20to%20their%20moral%20self-regard,%20which%20they%20addressed%20by%20putting%20him%20or%20her%20down,%20and%20reporting%20less%20respect%20for,%20and&source=bl&ots=B5mVqmsyZy&sig=ACfU3U0WDPWR6jwV8owCI0QTLrbM_IIZ3A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjb9f6plpnxAhXQ3mEKHcC4AysQ6AEwAnoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=the%20otherwise%20exemplary%20stance%20of%20the%20rebel%20apparently%20represented%20a%20threat%20to%20their%20moral%20self-regard%2C%20which%20they%20addressed%20by%20putting%20him%20or%20her%20down%2C%20and%20reporting%20less%20respect%20for%2C%20and&f=false)

Comment: It means "apart from", or "except". Their stance was examplary, but was disapproved by those particants who had acted differently. In other words, it wasn't examplary to them, so it seems a rather odd thing to say.

Comment: So, it was exemplary stance to everybody except them?

Comment: It says "To participants who had willingly gone along with the problematic behavior...." The peculiarity is like saying "this drink is first class, but tastes awful."

Answer (score 3):

> To participants who had willingly gone along with the problematic
> behavior, ***the otherwise exemplary stance of the rebel*** apparently
> represented a threat to their moral self-regard...

I understand it like this

> To those participants (...) the stance of the rebel *which would **normally/generally** be considered exemplary **if taken out of this particular context/in any other different context*** apparently
> represented a threat to their moral self-regard.

See this meaning and example given by [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/otherwise)

> except for what has just been referred to:
>
> - The poor sound quality ruined ***an otherwise beautiful film***.

Comment: +1 Interestingly if you take either your or my answer , both the alternative meanings of otherwise work in this case.  Different or "except for what has just been referred to" But there again "Except also means with this difference" according to the dictionary we are both using.

Comment: @Brad While I understand why you chose the meaning of "different" I am not sure you can simply replace "otherwise" with "different" without changing the meaning of the sentence. This is probably why whoever DVed you did so.

Comment: Agreed but conversely you cannot just place otherwise with either  *not including* or *except for what has just been referred to* as a direct replacement but that was not DVed so I assume some other reason. It is not unusually for my posts to be DVed even when the answers are undisputed. It has happen three times today already. But I am not here for points or praise I just want to help learners. I also learn things myself some of the guys on here are far out of my class.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is a simple ***dictionary definition; differently***

---

To participants who had willingly gone along with the problematic behaviour, *the different*, exemplary stance of the rebel apparently represented a threat to their moral self-regard

---

otherwise adverb (DIFFERENTLY)

differently, or in another way: Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/otherwise)